# Обфускация С++ кода и скрытие метаинформации из билда.

Tags: c++, обфускация

В общем, обращаюсь к тем, кто хорошо дружит с криптованием и обфускацией.

При компиллировании программы в MCVS2010 \ 2013, да и вообще где бы то ни было, выползает вот такая чушь, если билд открыть блокнотиком:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

А также список используемых библиотек и много прочей дряни.

В общем, как можно вырезать эту дрянь из готового билда без ущерба в работе программы?

Comment: Удалить жесткий с компа и разбить молотком. Один из самых надежных методов (после сжигания в термоядерной печи).

Comment: Интересно, как автор собрался обфусцировать используемые библиотеки, если при их отсутствии приложения падают с сообщением не могу найти библиотеку и далее полная инфа, что же именно не хватает, т.е. всегда можно понять, что именно используется. Собственно, и без запуска можно понять наверняка, просто в винде не знаю как (в никсах с помощью ldd).

Comment: @aknew на всякий случай - в винде для этого есть Dependency Walker, depends.exe

Answer (score 1):

Вкомпилируйте все библиотеки статически, включая системные, уберите все динамические зависимости. Учтите, что ваша программа будет непереносима и скорее всего будет работать только на той системе, на которой её скомпилировали.

Comment: @VladD, давайте я изложу поподробнее?

1. Это не программа, как таковая, а плагин.

2. Т.к. адекватного способа компилляции плагинов для этого нет, всё компиллится в VS10, с использованием неких сторонних библиотек.

Answer (score 0):

Какую цель Вы преследуете? Чем именно Вам этот XML не угодил? Почитайте тут: http://www.samlogic.net/articles/manifest.htm